# Android Studio Vitual Device on a Windows 7 VM not compatible

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, android-studio

I have a VirtualBox VM on my computer, the VM is running Windows 7 64bit. I installed Android Studio on that VM. I only have the basic Hello World application. When I try to run AVD I get this message:

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. Android Emulator is
>   incompatible with Hyper-V.
>
> Unfortunately, you cannot have Hyper-V running and use the emulator.
>   Here is hat you can do:
>
> 1) Start a command prompt as Administrator
>
> 2) Run the following command: C:\Windows\system32> bcdedit /set
>   hypervisorlaunchtype off
>
> 3) Reboot your machine.

I tried running this command and restart multiple time, doesn't change anything.

I also tried to do some port forwarding : http://paulsdevworld.blogspot.ca/2013/06/make-android-studio-work-with-androvm.html 
I was unable to connect `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I've check this question, I'm not having the same issue because OP has a android image directly in VirtualBox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252296/test-android-app-on-virtual-box-from-android-studio

I installed Intel HAXM but when I try to run it I get this message 
[image]

Those are my current settings, virtualization is clearly enabled. Is that the correct settings? [image]

Anyone knows a way to make this work or something that I could try?
Feel free to ask any question.

Comment: You can't install a product that requires the VT-x extension, within a virtual machine, that doesn't pass the VT-x extension to it.  In other words you can't run Android Studio within a VirtualBox virtual machine.  You have indeed allowed VirtualBox to use VT-x which means, you can install a 64-bit operating system on a virtual machine, running on a host which is running a 32-bit operating system

Comment: Alright then how else can I use android studio in an VM

Comment: I have had success using VMWare products.  I know VMWare Workstation allows you to run nested virtual machines which is basically what you need. While VirtualBox does allow you run nested virtual machine it clearly does not pass VT-x onto those machines.

Comment: I guess this defeats the entire purpose of using Virtualbox. So why bother putting those options in the settings? I simply don't get it. What a failure.

Comment: I have had some success by using an AVD that uses an ARM image.  In my case I chose Nougat / 25 / armeabi-v7a on the Other Images tab in the System Image step when creating an AVD.  Be warned the emulator runs super slow.

Comment: It's been a long time but I should probably link a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528076/android-studio-virtual-device-on-a-windows-7-vm-not-compatible